# How to instantiate UserControl and add Items to its Container in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have the following UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlTest.UserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="BasePanel"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And my MainWindwo.XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:UC="clr-namespace:UserControlTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel Name="dpMain">
    <UC:Control x:Name="ucBaseControl" />

</DockPanel>
```

In the code-behind MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace UserControlTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox tbWorld = new TextBox();
            tbWorld.Text = "Hello World";
            ucBaseControl.MainPanel.Children.Add(tbWorld);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in XAML to avoid code-behind?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hum you have a bigger issue: why is your main view responsible for the content of your UC? The goal of a UC is precisely to decouple them. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Hey Pragmateek, I have 2 Windows: The 1 Window is exact the UserControl. The 2nd window is the UserControl but with more UI Elements. The UserControl is something like my baseWindow. So if I will make changes to the UserControl both windows are affected something like inheritance

Comment: So you need to ask yourself are they both really the same kind of control then? The answer may still be yes, but if there are a fixed number of configurations of these controls (i.e. the contents they'll have) then why not just expose a property that controls which 'mode' your control is in? Then your main window (or any other window) doesn't need to add UI elements to your custom control, it just needs to set a single property.

Comment: Hi so first of all a Usercontrol is suposed to be a new self programmed control. That dose not mean that you are suposed to put multiple elements in it just so seperate them from your window.
In my example I was creating a MenuControl with a uniq style and some extra functionality and property. I wantet to use this MenuUserControl on several Windows and there should be divrent options each time! So I made the Menu once and defined the MenuItems in the xaml of its parent. I will post the solution as a normal comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do something like:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.BaseControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel x:Name="root">
        <TextBlock>I'm from base</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel x:Name="newPanel">

        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    [ContentProperty("NewControls")]
    public partial class BaseControl : UserControl
    {
        public UIElementCollection NewControls
        {
            get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(NewControlsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NewControlsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NewControlsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NewControls", typeof(UIElementCollection), typeof(BaseControl));

        public BaseControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.NewControls = new UIElementCollection(this, this);

            this.Loaded += BaseControl_Loaded;
        }

        void BaseControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (UIElement element in NewControls.Cast<UIElement>().ToList())
            {
                NewControls.Remove(element);

                this.newPanel.Children.Add(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the other control or window:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
...
<local:BaseControl>
    <TextBlock>I'm from new</TextBlock>
</local:BaseControl>
```

Not sure it perfectly fits your needs but may serve as a good base.

Comment: Your way is quite complicated

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution.

My UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucFancyMenu" x:Name="MySelf"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Label Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#F0F">So Fancy</Label>
        <ItemsControl Margin="0 30 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MySelf, Path=Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The UserControl Class:

```
<Markup.ContentProperty("Items")> _
Public Class ucFancyMenu

    Public Property Items As New List(Of UIElement)

End Class
```

How to use it in other Xamls:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>

        <local:ucFancyMenu>
            <Button>FancyBtn 1</Button>
            <Button>FancyBtn 2</Button>
            <Button>FancyBtn 3</Button>
            <Button>FancyBtn 4</Button>
            <Button>FancyBtn 5</Button>
            <Button>FancyBtn 6</Button>
            <Button>FancyBtn 7</Button>
        </local:ucFancyMenu>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If you want to use that to have your actions (Button Click) out of ypur "Menu" and inside your window you should rather use Commands.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/implementing-custom-commands/